# Display WCHAR Strings in Xcode Debugger

Tags: xcode, unicode, debugging, wchar

I'd like to preview WCHAR strings in the variable display of the Xcode 3.2 debugger.

Bascially if I have

```
 WCHAR wtext[128];
 wcscpy(wtext, L"Hello World");
```

I'd like to see "Hello World" for wtext when tracing into the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to write a Custom Data Formatter for your wchar types, complete with your assumption of what the byte width is and what the character encoding is. THe C++ standard does not specify either of these, which is why wchar and wstring are not very portable and not well-supported on Mac OS X.

One example, with caveats about how you have to customize it for your particular mode of use, is [here](http://developer.casgrain.com/?p=43).